# What is the regression test equivalent to a repeated measures (factorial) ANOVA?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

As in the title, I'm trying to figure out what would be the regression test equivalent to a repeated measures one- and two-way ANOVAs?

So, in the case of having different dichotomous IVs and two measurements in a continuous DV, what regression model should be used?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [Mixed Effects Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model).

Comment: What would "mixed" in this context mean? Would this model work with a fully balanced data of between- and within-subjects (i.e., all of the subjects have experienced the same conditions/treatments)?

Comment: @Linguister, did you read the Wikipedia page linked? Mixed in this sense means that there are both fixed and random effects. Fixed effects would be treatment and other fixed conditions, random effects are subjects (and possibly other effects that represent a sample from a larger population of interest). Mixed effects model do great with balanced data, but also work for non-balanced data.